# Android make button disabled after setting alpha 0

Tags: android, alpha

probably another rhetorical question.

In iOS when we set a view's (any any `UIView` subclass such as `UIButton`) alpha to 0, iOS by default disables all user interaction on that view.

I got an Android app where I animate fade out the view by:

```
ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buttonSelectionContainer, "alpha", 1, 0);
fadeOut.setDuration(500);
fadeOut.start();
```

However, I am noticing that when I tap the screen, the animation starts again, leading me to believe, in Android, even when a button alpha is set to 0, it is still tappable, is this true?

Is there a way to globally tell Android to disable user interaction for a view **(and all its subviews)** when its alpha is set to 0, either explicitly through using:

```
view.setAlpha(0.0f);
```

or through the `ObjectAnimator` like the above code block I used ?

A temporary work around for my problem would probably be to schedule this code to run after 500 ms:

```
// psuedocode: after 500ms
dispatch_doSomethingAfter(500)
{
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Not the ideal solution but might be my only solution, unless some bright Android developers out there has a better solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `addListener` on your `ObjectAnimator` to control what happens after the animation has finished.

```
fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                 button.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
});
```

Comment: :( I don't know if that's an ideal solution. Wouldn't this mean I would need to manually tell it which button I want disabled ?

Comment: Yes. It's better than running a thread to disable the button after some time because you wouldn't know if the animation has actually completed

Comment: Just another pain point - if you have a 10 buttons inside a container view e.g. a `LinearLayout`, setting the layout `setEnable(false)` does NOT prevent the subviews (each of your 10 buttons) from being tappable. One would need to manually set all those 10 buttons to disabled. That would also mean if I decide to set the layout container to be enabled, I would also need to manually tell all my subviews to be enabled. Maybe setting `duplicateParentState` to true when setting up the subviews, offer some salvation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Animator.AnimatorListener` that **automatically** disables the target `View` when the animation ends.

Declare your custom `DisableViewOnEndAnimatorListener` class:

```
public class DisableViewOnEndAnimatorListener extends AnimatorListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        if (animation instanceof ObjectAnimator) {
            final Object target = ((ObjectAnimator) animation).getTarget();
            if (target instanceof View) {
                ((View) target).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
DisableViewOnEndAnimatorListener endAnimatorListener = new DisableViewOnEndAnimatorListener();

ObjectAnimator button1FadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button1, "alpha", 1, 0);
button1FadeOut.setDuration(500);
button1FadeOut.addListener(endAnimatorListener);
button1FadeOut.start();

ObjectAnimator button2FadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button2, "alpha", 1, 0);
button2FadeOut.setDuration(500);
button2FadeOut.addListener(endAnimatorListener);
button2FadeOut.start();
```